AWS ECS service connecting to RDS instance fails when I add an ALB
I have a Laravel app that I've dockerized and the image is pushed to ECR. The app is connecting to an RDS database hosted on the same VPC. I've created a cluster and service on ECS. Without the ALB, I'm able to access the public IP assigned to the running task. The docker image is running a DB migration, and it's successfully connecting and migrating the data, but once I've created the service and added an ALB, it's building the app but fails on connecting to the RDS DB, saying that it timed out.
The security group for the ALB allows inbound traffic to port 80, and the security group for the service to ALB connection has inbound traffic allow all TCP from the ALB security group.

The load balancer can't possibly be the reason for the failed RDS connection.  The load balancer only proxies requests from the user to the Fargate service. The load balancer is not involved in any way with the network connection between your ECS Fargate service and the RDS instance. There has to be some other change that you made when you were hooking up the load balancer to the service that caused this. What do the logs for the service (in CloudWatch Logs) say exactly when the failure occurs? Please include the actual error message in your question.

Could be that you are mixing up a gateway timeout (504) with a database connection timeout, where the former can be the result of a misconfiguration between the application and the alb. Also, you may need to look at the idle timeout on the alb, which I think defaults to 60 seconds. If that value is set to a value that is less than the time i takes to request and return data, then you will likely see receive 504 as well.

@MarkB here's what the cloud watch log says:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as name, (data_length + index_length) as size, table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test_table and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)
In the entrypoint.sh script I'm running php artisan migrate:fresh. I can access the login page, but the DB is never migrated

That definitely sounds like a network connection error in the database connection. However it absolutely cannot be caused by placing a load balancer in front of the ECS task. Something else had to have changed to cause this. Check that the RDS security group allows access from the ECS security group.
